# How to make all possible sequences but the method like n-grams

Tags: python, python-3.x, for-loop, n-gram

newbie asks. I want to make a program like this:

```
example: text = 'I playing basketball today'

2 gram > 'I playing', 'I basketball', 'I today',
         'playing I', 'playing basketball', 'playing today',
         'basketball I', 'basketball playing', 'basketball today',
         'today I', 'today playing', 'today basketball'
3 gram > 'I playing basketball', 'I basketball today', 'I playing today',
         'playing I basketball', 'playing I today', 'playing basketball today',
         'basketball I playing', 'basketball I today', 'basketball playing today', etc.
etc gram.
```

I use n-grams and get like this

```
2 gram > 'I play', 'play basketball', 'basketball today'
3 gram > 'I play basketball', 'play basketball today'
```

How to manipulate like an example? or is this possible to make?

I don't know what method name it is, so I can't find it on google

Sorry for the confusing question, thank you for your help.

Comment: Try using [`itertools.permutations`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.permutations) after using `example.split()`, and then using `' '.join` to join them back into sentences.

Comment: `list(permutations('I playing basketball today'.split(' '), r = 2))` for `2 gram` change `r` accordingly

Comment: Thank you guys, it really helps me a lot!